# How to limit block activity (insertion/deletion) to inside of a Block Template on the Admin Screen?

Tags: templates, block-editor

I have created a Block Template.  However, I can still insert blocks below the Block Template on the Admin screen. Is there a way to disable any block activity below the Block Template on the Admin screen?

Answer (score 0):

I added an action on enqueue_block_editor_assets and added custom css to remove the Block List Appender.

Similar to removing the title in this link:  https://generatepress.com/forums/topic/when-editing-in-gutenberg-remove-the-title-from-the-editing-interface/

Here is the code...

```
function remove_default_block_list_appender() {
    //Check to make sure you on an admin page
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'custom-style-for-default-block-list-appender',
            __DIR__ . '/build/index.css'
        );

        $custom_css = "
            .block-list-appender {
                display: none;
            }";
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style-for-default-block-list-appender', $custom_css );
    }
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'remove_default_block_list_appender' );
```

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.